# Simple reactJS website using wordpress backend

Tags: wordpress, reactjs

I have a basic wordpress site at the moment, I would like to use a basic react frontend to display articles in my blog.

Can anyone tell me how I can hook the back end up to react?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to build a rest `API` within your `wordpress` site, you would then make calls to the rest api from your react app. Check here:

http://v2.wp-api.org/

A very simple example from the above link:

```
<?php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'route', '/author/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
    ) );
} );
```

So basically you'd be able to simply integrate the rest api into your existing wordpress functions!

On your react site you'd simple use a ***fetch or ajax*** to grab the data! Checkout the fetch api here:

https://github.com/github/fetch

You could follow a tutorial, such as this one:

https://lamosty.com/2015/09/07/react-single-page-wordpress-rest-api-theme-tutorial/

Comment: Latest WP versions have a REST API built in, no need for a plugin -- https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/